# Codeception api test with Laravel5 module: withoutWrapping() applied on single JsonResource affects other tests

Tags: laravel, testing, codeception

I have codeception api tests with Laravel5 module in several Cest files.
If I run all api tests `codecept run api`. Test after api resource that contains `MyResource::withoutWrapping();` affects other api responses on other Cest File (it removes 'data' wrapping from api response).
Is it possible to avoid that behavior? I don't want to apply `withoutWrapping()` to other api resources, that follows after...

```
# api.suite.yml
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
              url: /api
              depends: Laravel5
        - \Helper\Api
        - Asserts
        - Laravel5:
              environment_file: .env.testing
```

```php
// Controller Api endpoint
    public function show(Event $event)
    {
        EventResource::withoutWrapping();
        return new EventResource($event->load([
            'eventRoomPrices', 'hotel.availableRoomCategories']));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call the opposite of `MyResource::withoutWrapping()` at the end of that test method or in `_after` method of that Cest class.

Is there a `MyResource::withWrapping()` method?

Comment: For example: `EventResource::$wrap = 'data';` 
It's looks like codeception starts one instance of laravel for api suite run.
Another way is to create `ResourceCollection class` with explicit return of array with ```$this->collection``` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections